# Separated by years, months, days of the date

Tags: php, date

how can separate year, month, day in date. and each put in variable?

```
1390/02/05
$year = '1390';
$month = '02';
$day = '05';
```

With respect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('/', '1390/02/05', 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('1390/02/05');
$year = date('Y', $timestamp);
$month = date('m', $timestamp);
$day = date('d', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
$date = '1390/02/05';
$array = $explode('/', $date);

$year = $array[0];
$month = $array[1];
$day = $array[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('/', '1390/02/09', 3);
```